# Mouseover option of select for IE

Tags: jquery, select, mouseover

I'm using IE7. I want to have show a description in the page for each option in the select box when the mouse is over the option. So as starting I wrote the code which shows the option value in the text box when mouse is over an option. But it never works. It works as if a change event.

```
<input name="selectedValue" id="selectedValue" >
<select id="TestCombo" name="TestCombo" >
     <option value="0" selected="selected">Zero</option>    
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( function() {
    $('#TestCombo option').mouseover( function() {
          $('#selectedValue').val($('#TestCombo option:selected').val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Basically this event won't work cross-browser, blame IE for messing that one up since IE6.  As an aside your `$().ready(` syntax is deprecated, use either `$(function() {` or the longer: `$(document).ready( function() {`

Comment: You're using IE7? As in that's your main browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the description to show up on **mouseover**, not on **change**, I think it's better to use tooltips. That can be done with HTML's `title` attribute, no JS needed.

**Example:**

```
<input name="selectedValue" id="selectedValue">
<select id="TestCombo" name="TestCombo" >
  <option title="Nothing." value="0" selected="selected">Zero</option>    
  <option title="The smallest number that has a meaning." value="1">One</option>
  <option title="Look, another small number!" value="2">Two</option>
  <option title="RGB - Red-Green-Blue. That's three colors!" value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nope!! The description is a mixture of so many fields. So we'll be posting a jsp page itslef using jquery by passing option value on which mouse over happens

Comment: Then sorry, but I can't understand your question. Your code doesn't do anything (at least in Chrome), whatever I do.

Comment: I'm just at beginning stage. I just want to tell you it is not just tool tips.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you want to do now! Experimenting with it…

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not a standard web practice. I'm not saying its wrong, I can see why you'd want to do something like this. I think your answer is to not bother with the select control and try finding or designing a control that works with input elements instead and mimic what 'select' is doing. It wouldn't be that difficult and in the end you would probably have greater control and cross-browser capability.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a plugin of some kind (like [this one](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/)) that is cross-browser compatible and manipulates `ul`'s to look like a `select` dropdown.

Unfortunately IE dropped the ball on `select` elements and gives you little to no control of them.