# How do I determine what option is underneath the mouse in a select dropdown menu?

Tags: jquery, html

I am having trouble implementing the following behaviour in a dropdown menu with jQuery. I'd like it so when a user mousesover one of the options, a div is highlighted. A quick google search showed me an "non-jquery" way of doing this, which I've created a fiddle for here:

http://jsfiddle.net/RY5r4/

```
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">

function showSelectValue(e) {
if (e.target.id!= 'select') {
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = e.target.value;
}
}

function attachTest() {
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('mouseover',showSelectValue,false);
}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="attachTest()">

<div id="test">Something Here</div>

<select id="select">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
<option value="4">Four</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

This effect roughly demonstrates the desired effect. The text is changed based on what option the user has selected (no clicks are required to select). I've currently implemented an `onMouseOver` handler to my select, but I am having problems determining what option is highlighted. How to I accomplish this?

Comment: I am not sure what you want but use `e.target.text` to get option's text. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/RY5r4/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/skram/RY5r4/5/ for both text and value.

Comment: In case it's any use to anybody, the script moved into the ... script part of jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RY5r4/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translated to jQuery:

```
$('#select').mouseover(function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != 'select') {
    $('#test').text(e.target.value);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/RY5r4/7/

This if course only works in browsers where a `select` element actually is displayed as a dropdown list. Also, Internet Explorer doesn't support this.

Comment: Only seems to work on Firefox, but has been the best answer so far. I don't really care about IE, but it doesn't seem to work on chrome. Any suggestions?

Comment: @duffmandrinkduff: Not really, if it's not supported it's doubtful that it's possible at all. It seems only a few browsers treat the options as elements, which is not so surprising as there is nothing in the standards that says that the option tags should be turned into actual DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's no way to do this; or at least no way to do it that's even remotely cross-browser compatible.  As mentioned in [Mouseover option of select for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292061/mouseover-option-of-select-for-ie), you might try jQuery UI Selectmenu:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/