# how to show select box options on mouse over?

Tags: jquery, select, mouseover

I have a drop down select box which have some options. When we click on the drop down then the drop down expands and all the options are displayed.

But I want this functionality with mouserover instead of clicking.

I want to display all the options on mouseover. Any one who have some idea about this?

**UPDATED**

I am using styledSelect jQuery plugin. Now this plugin converts the html select box to div and li based select box.
[Here is the plugin documentation](http://code.google.com/p/lnet/wiki/jQueryStyledSelectOverview)

Comment: Sup man, read this - what you are trying to do is not standard html practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292061/mouseover-option-of-select-for-ie

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you had in mind but it may be in the right direction.

```
function toggleSelectBox(selbox) {
    if (selbox.size > 1) { //HIDE:
        selbox.size = 1;
        selbox.style.position = 'static';
    } else { //SHOW:
        selbox.size = selbox.options.length;
        selbox.style.position = 'absolute';
        selbox.style.height = 'auto';
    }
}


<select id="type" name="type" onmouseout="toggleSelectBox(this)" onmouseover="toggleSelectBox(this)">
    <option value="">opt1</option>
    <option value="">opt2</option>
    <option value="">opt3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us what your working with regarding your update.
"I am using styledSelect jQuery plugin"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS to acheive your task. You cant do it with the classical select box of html. Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bk2HA/8/) you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could only use your select as the part of DOM tree to build some mouseOver drop div with this "option" information that you could access as the select children. So i think you may only simulate select on mouseOver.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing, The order in which you references your script file also plays a part, rather have your jquery file before you add reference to the js file you create to overwrite that function. it will work but not in safari for some odd reason